# Prove there must be a neighborhood of of $z_0$ such that $f(z)\neq0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be continuous for all z. Show that if $f(z_0)≠ 0$, then there must be a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $f(z)≠0$. This is assuming z is a complex number of the form $ z = x+iy$.

I started saying $|f(z) - f(z_0)| < \epsilon $ and $|z - z_0| < \delta $ but i'm very confused about the next step of the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Set $$\epsilon = \frac{|f(z_0)|}{2} > 0$$

Then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that ***_*__*_*__*_***